# filemaker app trying to connect to square register app

Tags: filemaker, square, square-connect

I have a filemaker file that was converted to an ios app through the ios app sdk filemaker and I was able to set up the app to switch to the square register app on the same ipad when it did a transaction. Everything was working well until I had to update the ios of the ipad from 9 to ios 10. So in order for the filemaker file app to work on ios10 I used the ios app sdk 15 that converts the filemaker file to an app that will work with ios 10 ipads. After doing this the app now is not able to switch to the square register app from the filemaker app. I get an error "No call back url specified". I never had any errors in the earlier version so am wondering if this has to do with the ios app sdk 15 changes or anything else? in my square register account I have specified the bundle id of the filemaker app, and the url scheme which is fmp for filemaker. Since its a native api not a web api I did not have to put a call back url.
and in the xcode settings for the filemaker app I have added the url scheme as fmp and also the bundle id of the app. I have also added in the filemaker app the following code that is sent to square register through the open url function ...

```
"square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data={
    "amount_money": {
        "amount": " & $payamt & “,
        "callback_url": “fmp",
        "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "client_id": "application-id”,
    "version": "1.2",
    "notes": "" & $reqno & "",
    "options": {
        "supported_tender_types": [
            "CREDIT_CARD"
        ]
    }
}”
```

in the above code previously I never had the call back url added and it worked perfect, but is that something I may need to add now?
and the application id is of course the application id from the square register account's app settings.
also above the version was previously 1.0 which I changed to 1.2 now - and the whole of the code above I converted to percent encoded text while sending it.
Please anyone let me know if you have similar issues.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm which version of the Square Point of Sale app you have?

Comment: Also, it looks like you have added the `callback_url` parameter into the the `amount_money` instead of the higher level object.

Comment: the square point version is 4.59. The running code I have has the callback url in the right place, after the amount_money braces, just below the clientid, yes noticed I had pasted in wrong above but the code has it placed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

"fmp" - is a prefix for FileMaker Go, not for your iOS App SDK.

You should change "fmp" prefix to your own, that you can find in Xcode settings: Project:Targets->Info->URL Types->URL Schemes. If it blank, you should to choose some and adjust your string:

"callback_url": “fmp"

Comment: In my xcode settings also I had placed fmp as the url scheme. So that's why I used the same scheme in the code i'm sending in. Previously I had fmp as the url scheme in xcode and in the code above I omitted the callback url line and it worked perfectly. In the sense I didn't really need the square register app to switch back to my filemaker app as soon as it was done because I didn't need to do anything with the return data so I didn't really need a callback url. But now am wondering if it's compulsory to have a callback url specified in the code above. Maybe it wasn't earlier?

Comment: I don't know what url scheme to use for this filemaker app since it isn't really using filemaker go (because it is transformed into an ios app with the ios app sdk 15 ) but also it not's really a web app also and hence there's no url I can use to go to it via the web. it's almost like a native app, but doesn't use filemaker go.

Comment: Even with native apps you need a callback URL, but it is the native app. The fact that it used to work without one must have been some kind of bug.

Comment: ok i added a custom url scheme and now get a new error "client id not specified" but i have already specified it as the application id from my square developer portal. Here's my new code.
    
   "square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data={
    "amount_money": {
        "amount": " & $payamt & “, 
        "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "callback_url": “zkln",
    "client_id": "application-id”,
    "version": "1.2",
    "notes": "" & $reqno & "",
    "options": {
        "supported_tender_types": [
            "CREDIT_CARD"
        ]
    }
}”

Comment: You need to enter your "client_id" (replace "application-id” )
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-ios?q=client_id

Your Application ID, available from your application dashboard:
https://connect.squareup.com/apps